# Group two tables by month and make difference

Tags: sql, openoffice-base

I try to regroup data (with SQL) by months and make a subtraction (with groups by months).

TABLE 1 :

| DATE | MONEY1. |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 30 |
| 10/01/2023 | 5 |
| 12/02/2023 | 30 |
| 18/02/2023 | 20 |

TABLE 2 :

| DATE | MONEY2. |
| --- | --- |
| 04/01/2023 | 5 |
| 8/01/2023 | 10 |
| 19/02/2023 | 5 |
| 20/02/2023 | 5 |

And I want to get this as my result:

| MONTH | MONEY1. | MONEY2. | MONEY1-MONEY2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 35 | 15 | 20 |
| February | 50 | 10 | 40 |

Thank you for your help !

I can group by month each table (in separate `SELECT` commands), but I can't make two operations in same table.

Comment: When asking a `SQL` question, please always tag the actual database and give the version you are using. Without simply answering your question, I am giving you a hint instead: you say you can group by month separately; so research sub-queries (in particular `cte`), especially how to join sub-queries on a common column (the month in your case). You learn far more by working it out yourself than by someone giving you a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and appropriate function to extract month from your date (in the example oracle dialect is being used) to sum money in your tables. And the join those aggregated results:

```sql
with t1 as(
    select sum(MONEY1) sum1, TRUNC(date_, 'MM') mon from table1
    group by TRUNC(date_, 'MM')
),
t2 as (
    select sum(MONEY2) sum2, TRUNC(date_, 'MM') mon from table2
    group by TRUNC(date_, 'MM')
)
select coalesce(t1.mon,t2.mon), sum1, sum2, sum1-sum2
from t1
full outer join t2
on (t1.mon=t2.mon)
```

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AfMzS0Hm).

For BASE query would look something like this:

```sql
select coalesce(t1.yea,t2.yea), coalesce(t1.mon,t2.mon), sum1, sum2, sum1-sum2
from (
    select sum(MONEY1) sum1, YEAR(date) yea, MONTH(date) mon 
    from table1
    group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) t1
full outer join (
    select sum(MONEY2) sum2, YEAR(date) yea, MONTH(date) mon
    from table2
    group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) t2
on (t1.mon=t2.mon and t1.yea=t2.yea)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I don't use Oracle but BASE in OpenOffice. Is it possible that your code isn't compatible ?

Comment: @bloumk, it indeed will be incompatible. I've added to answer how approximately would look query in BASE, but I'm not familiar, so double check it.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that "with" works in libreOffice ?

Comment: @bloumk, as I said, I'm not familiar with oo-base, so no guaranties. I've changed CTE to sub-queries: on the first glance to google it seems they are supported. But I'm afraid that's all I can here.

Comment: When I adapt your code, I have en error message: "Column not found: t2.mon in statement [SELECT COALESCE ( "t1"."mon", "t2"."mon" ), "sum1", "sum2", "sum1" - "sum2" FROM ( SELECT SUM( "MONEY1" ) "sum1", YEAR( "DATE" ) "yea", MONTH( "DATE" ) "mon" FROM "TABLE1" GROUP BY YEAR( "DATE" ), MONTH( "DATE" ) ) "t1" FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT SUM( "MONEY2" ) "sum2", YEAR( "DATE" ) "yea", MONTH( "DATE" ) "mon" FROM "TABLE2" GROUP BY YEAR( "DATE" ), MONTH( "DATE" ) ) "t2" ON ( "t1"."mon" = "t2"."mon" AND "t1"."yea" = "t2"."yea" )] "

Can you help me ? 

This is my code:

Comment: select coalesce(t1.mon,t2.mon), sum1, sum2, sum1-sum2
from (select 
  sum("MONEY1") sum1, 
  YEAR("DATE") yea, 
  MONTH("DATE") mon 
    from "TABLE1"

    group by YEAR("DATE"), MONTH("DATE")) t1

full outer join (
     select 
  sum("MONEY2") sum2, 
  YEAR("DATE") yea, 
  MONTH("DATE") mon
    from "TABLE2"
    group by YEAR("DATE"), MONTH("DATE")) t2
on (t1.mon=t2.mon and t1.yea=t2.yea)